# Adding Bootstrap 5 to Angular 13

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I want to add bootstrap to angular. Specifically I'm having problems displaying icons from the library using code like

```
<i class="bi bi-star"></i>
```

I've added the line

```
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

in angular.json. I've also added

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

in styles.scss. Some funtions of bootstrap have been implemented on the app such as the formatting of buttons but it won't recognize bootstrap classes.

I hope I was clear. I'm just starting out and it's my first query on SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to install icon bootstrap too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365440/how-to-programmatically-use-bootstrap-icons-in-an-angular-project/62780730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is what solved it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365440/how-to-programmatically-use-bootstrap-icons-in-an-angular-project/62780730)

Turns out the icons are now in a different module called bootstrap-icons and you have to import it separatelty.

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Solution 1:
Write it to angular.json

```
"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"],
"scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"]
```

Solution 2:
import bootstrap to style.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: I ran npm again and I added those lines of code. I restarted ng serve. Everything looks the same as before. It doesn't recognize bootstrap classes and I can't insert icons by changing the class of an element. Everything else looks like bootstrap.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please try the solution 2.

Comment: for icons there is seperate css you can look in node_modules/bootstrap

Comment: don't forget to restart angular application after doing changes in 'angular.json' file.

Comment: @mullern change the bootsrap spelling in ur answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add Bootstrap 5 to your project is by pasting the href in the index.html on the header.